# How to display an additional column along with all the columns in oracle db

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

The scenario is that, I want to write a query to display all  the columns of a table along with an additional column.

E.g.:

I want to display all the columns and rows of jobs table,
which can be done by
 **select * from jobs;**

Now I also want the diff between min_salary and max_ salary to be displayed along with all the others columns.
So I did try like,
 **select *, max_salary - min_salary salaryDiff from jobs;**
this is not a valid query, it shows.

So I tried the traditional way,
**select job_id, job_title, min_salary, max_salary, max_salary - min_salary salaryDiff from jobs;**
this works.

This is not a tough job since in the above example it has only 4 columns, but, what if a table has 10 or 20 columns and we ran into a scenario like this?
is traditional way the only way?
or
is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prefix the `*` with the table name (or its alias) that the star refers:

```
select jobs.*, max_salary - min_salary salaryDiff from jobs;
```

Same thing, but with an alias:

```
select j.*, max_salary - min_salary salaryDiff from jobs j;
```